# Запрос через Python к MySQL выдает None

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

Делаю запрос к Mysql следующим образом:

```py
def get_balance(authorid):
    try:
        with connect(
            host="localhost",
            user="root",
            password="pass",
            database='users') as connection:
                select = f"""SELECT Username,ID FROM user where ID={authorid}"""
                with connection.cursor(buffered=True) as cursor:
                    print(cursor.execute(select))
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)

get_balance(386485048087543819)
```

И в ответ получаю None.
Если делаю точно такой же запрос через Command Line то получаю правильный ответ.

```
+----------+--------------------+
| Username | ID                 |
+----------+--------------------+
| ????S    | 386485048087543819 |
+----------+--------------------+
```

Подключение к базе идет нормальное и работает возможность четния и записи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил, добавил `cursor.fetchall()`

Конечный рабочий код:

```py
def get_balance(authorid):
    try:
        with connect(
            host="localhost",
            user="root",
            password="sss",
            database='users') as connection:
                select = f"""SELECT Username,ID FROM user where ID={authorid}"""
                with connection.cursor(buffered=True) as cursor:
                    cursor.execute(select)
                    return cursor.fetchall()
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)

get_balance(386485048087543819)
```